# Rails ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in ArticlesController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in ArticlesController#destroy

SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ?
```

I'm creating a blog app, I get this error every time I try to delete an article that has comments  in it. How can I fix it?

Let me know what code to post and I will update the question.

Articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def index
     #@articles = Article.all
     @articles = Article.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

     def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if @article.update(article_params)
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
    end
end

private
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :datee)
end
```

Articles model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    has_many :photos
end
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

Now I have a new error

```
ArgumentError in ArticlesController#destroy

Unknown key: :dependant. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type, :index_errors
```

Comment: In the error the solution is already there correct the spelling of dependent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid this problem you could define `dependent: :delete_all` in `Article` model so every related `Comment` is also deleted, like this:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Answer (score 18):

Using `dependent: :delete_all` does not use validation thus it is directly deleting records without validating properly. Use `dependent: :destroy` if you want your records to be validated safely.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: what do you mean by validation? a record will be deleted, so whey do you need validation?

Comment: I found this http://notes.jerzygangi.com/dependent-destroy-vs-dependent-delete-all-in-rails-models/

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the other correct answers :

In many scenarios, you may actually want to conserve the associated models and just delete the foreign key in the associated tables :

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :nullify
end
```

If you are building a blog module for instance, you are obligated by law to archive users comments for while before actual deletion. So you want to comply to it, I may as well suggest that you use a soft deletion system, such as [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia), [act_as_paranoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) or [discard](https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard) :

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  act_as_paranoid

  # Not accurate, but here is approximatively what the gem does :
  # default_scope where(deleted_at: nil)

  has_many :comments, dependent: :delete_all # or :destroy if you have callbacks in Comment model

  def self.clean
    only_deleted.where('destroyed_at < ?', Date.today - 6.month).destroy_fully!
  end
end
```

This way, when you remove an article, the comments wont get destroyed, neither will the article itself. You can then setup some cron tasks ([whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to perform the actual deletion after legal retention time passed :

```
# Whenever: schedule.rb
every 1.day, at: '4:30 am' do
  runner "Article.clean"
end
```

I did not test the code and it's a bit off topic, but I hope it helps.

Cheers !